# Get the merge files names in the git log command

Tags: git, github, git-log

We are using the below command to get the commits for a particular date range. However it is able to identify the merge (commits) from a different branch. But its not providing the merge list of file names in the output.

Sample command which we are using is given below,

```
git log --after="11/29/2016" --before="11/20/2016"  --pretty='format:%cd %h' --name-status --date=short-local
```

How to get the list of merge file names in the above command.

Comment: What are you seeing in particular? And what is missing? The command you've provided [shows the files](https://gist.github.com/cluePrints/f29b4c9ecd83da68b1ba8ed9ef1554ed) list for me

Comment: We are too able to view the files for commits. However for the merged files it just shows the date and its SHA value and does not gives the file names. Example 11/26/2016 f45e45

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--name-only` flags. Sample output:

```
$ git log --after="11/09/2016" --before="11/20/2016" --pretty='format:%cd %h' -m --name-only
Fri Nov 18 16:05:18 2016 +0530 2d28b46
shop/booking.py
shop/cancellation.py
shop/tasks.py

Fri Nov 18 15:25:54 2016 +0530 e614e73
shop/booking.py
shop/cancellation.py

Fri Nov 18 15:19:14 2016 +0530 34b5bcd
shop/booking.py
shop/cancellation.py
```

From the git-log manpage:

```
  --name-only
       Show only names of changed files.
```

Comment: Yes its working. However its giving all the files which have came for merging with the branch. We need only the merged and committed files in the output.

Comment: @Skyrim Add current output you get and sample output needed by you in the probem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--stat` flag.

```
$ git log --after="11/29/2016" --before="11/20/2016" --date=short-local --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" --stat
```

Comment: Nop its not working still giving same output Example 11/26/2016 f45e45. And no file names are displayed for merged commits.

Comment: Updated answer. Can you add a demo example in your OP so that it would be clear the format are your concern?